# How to format the times and get a time delta in R using chron

Tags: r, datetime, time, timedelta, chron

I have two time points, I would like to obtain a time delta (notice that my times have milliseconds). I have tried to use the Chron package :

```
library(chron)
t1<- '2022/06/28 - 10:45:40:124'
t2<-'2022/06/28 - 10:54:50:193'
chron(t1, format='%Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in parse.format(format): unrecognized format %Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S:%f
Traceback:

1. chron("2022/06/28 - 10:45:40:124", format = "%Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S:%f")
2. convert.dates(dates., format = fmt, origin. = origin.)
3. parse.format(format)
4. stop(paste("unrecognized format", format))
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.chron` and fix the format.

```
fmt <- '%Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S:%OS'
t1c <- as.chron(t1, format = fmt)
t2c <- as.chron(t2, format = fmt)

# use any of these depending on what you want
t2c - t1c
difftime(t2c, t1c, units = "days")
difftime(t2c, t1c, units = "hours")    
difftime(t2c, t1c, units = "mins")
difftime(t2c, t1c, units = "secs")
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `parse_date` from `parsedate`

```
library(parsedate)
 parse_date(t1) - parse_date(t2)
Time difference of -9.166667 mins
```

---

Or using `chron`

```
library(chron)
 t1new <- sub(":(\\d+)$", ".\\1", trimws(t1, whitespace = ".*-\\s*"))
t2new <- sub(":(\\d+)$", ".\\1", trimws(t2, whitespace = ".*-\\s*"))
chron(times = t2new, format = c(times = "h:m:s")) - 
   chron(times = t1new, format = c(times = "h:m:s"))
[1] 00:09:10
```